# i have get error heap error using constructor ( use memory dinamic char *t = new char [10] t ="test123456";) and in distructor delete [] t; error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

error heap memory, memory corruption, #181 just don't understand it. Some time try use copy ctor and it the same error. Can You explain me

```
Test::Test() {
    desc = new char[4];`
    desc = "Try";
} 

Test::~Test() {delete [] desc; }
```

Answer (score 3):

It fails because you do not understand basics of C++.

```
desc = new char[4]; desc = "Try";
```

This line of code first allocates memory for 4 characters, returns the pointer to allocated memory and stores it in `desc`. However, the next moment you completely lose this pointer, and now assign "Try" (a string literal) to `desc`. Now your `desc` points to "Try".

Here

```
Test::~Test() {delete [] desc; }
```

you delete the pointer, which points to "Try" - as if you would do `delete "Try"`. But you can't delete a string literal, you did not create a it.

Hence the crash.

Comment: He probably meant to copy the string, e.g. strncpy(desc, "Try" 4);